# Symfony ManyToMany duplicate entry

Tags: php, many-to-many, symfony4

I have a problem when I want to insert data with relation ManyToMany.

When I want to create a new Category, with my CategoryType, I want only the name's field.
In my AdminCategoryController, I want to force a Site, by get the DOMAIN SERVER where I work.

**UPDATE**
I fact, I've many site with many domain. All Sites must to connect on one only database, with his servername.
So my VHOST is configured for that.

So, I have 2 entity : Site, Category

**SiteEntity** :

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SiteRepository")
 */
class Site
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $domain;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", mappedBy="site")
     */
    private $categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDomain(): ?string
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    public function setDomain(string $domain): self
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $category->addSite($this);
            $this->categories[] = $category;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if ($this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories->removeElement($category);
            $category->removeSite($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**CategoryEntity :**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Site", inversedBy="categories", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $site;

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __construct(Site $site)
    {
        $this->site = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Site[]
     */
    public function getSite(): Collection
    {
        return $this->site;
    }

    public function addSite(Site $site): self
    {
        if (!$this->site->contains($site)) {
            $this->site[] = $site;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSite(Site $site): self
    {
        if ($this->site->contains($site)) {
            $this->site->removeElement($site);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I get the Site's infos in **SiteService** with session :

```
use App\Repository\SiteRepository;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class SiteService{

    public $infos;

    private $session;
    private $requestStack;

    private $siteRepository;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, RequestStack $requestStack, SiteRepository $siteRepository){
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->siteRepository = $siteRepository;

        $this->getInfos();
    }

    public function getInfos(){
        $this->infos = $this->session->get('site');
        if(empty($this->infos)){
            $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
            $server_name = $request->server->get('SERVER_NAME');
            $this->infos = $this->siteRepository->findOneBy(['domain'=>$server_name]);
            if($this->infos == NULL){
                $this->infos = $this->siteRepository->findOneBy([]);
            }
            $this->session->set('site', $this->infos);
            $this->infos = $this->session->get('site');
        }
        return $this->infos;
    }
}
```

And here is my **CategoryController** to add a new Category in Site

```
 /**
 * @Route("/new", name="admin.category.new")
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function new(Request $request):Response{
    $category = new Category();

    $form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $category);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $server_name = $request->server->get('SERVER_NAME');
    $site = $this->siteRepository->findBy(['domain'=>$server_name]);

    $siteFromSession = $this->session->get('site');

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $category->addSite($site);
        $this->em->persist($category);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.category.edit', ['id'=>$category->getId()]);
    }

    $form = $form->createView();
    $params = compact('category', 'form');
    return $this->render('admin/category/new.html.twig', $params);
}
```

The two variable dump is not equal..

**dump($site);**

```
Site {#187 ▼
  -id: 1
  -name: "My Website"
```

**dump($siteFromSession);**

```
Site {#623 ▼
  -id: 1
  -name: "My Website"
```

If I persist Category with *$category->addSite($site);*
It's work.

But when I persist Category with *$category->addSite($siteFromSession);*
I see in my database the current Site is duplicate in Site table and category.site is the new site, not the site what I doing insert.

But, I don't want execute a query each time I add a category.
I want to use session to get Site's infos only the first time, when I was login in admin page

Thank to help me

Comment: Why the reluctance to do a db query when adding a category? At some point you have to tell doctrine to use your existing site, otherwise it just looks like a new site.

Comment: The variable `SERVER_NAME` returns the main domain, as set in the apache `ServerName` directive. You don't give any information on how you `VirtualHost` are set up, but I'd say using `HTTP_HOST` will solve your problem.

Comment: For VHost and ServerName, I've update my post.
With Site infos in session, i can switch to all my websites, in admin's pages.
So I can not imagine making a request each time to know on which site I want to add / modify an item, in the admin.
Do you know why object return it's not the same ?
Site #187 and Site #623 but with the good primary key (1)

Comment: I realize, it's really site's infos from session is the problem
In other forum, they speak about to merge object site from session. But i've always the error : A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\CategorySite#site' that was not configured to cascade.
But if I add cascade=persist, this duplicate entry site to id : 3, name: "My Website"

Comment: SO !! I've resolved!
When I want to save the site info in session, I detach this, and when I want to get the entity from the session, I merge this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO !! I've resolved!
When I want to save the site info in session, I detach this, and when I want to get the entity from the session, I merge this one

```
public function setInfos(){
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $server_name = $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');
    $site = $this->siteRepository->findOneBy(['domain'=>$server_name]);
    $this->em->detach($site);
    $this->session->set('site', $site);
}

public function getInfos()
    $site = $this->session->get('site');
    $site = $this->em->merge($site);
}
```